# How to construct a sentence with "Hm" in SSML

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, ssml

How can I construct word "hm" with Alexa SSML? I have tried this, but it is not completely natural. Please advice.

```
<speak>
    <emphasis level="strong"><p>Hm.</p></emphasis> 
    You are right.
</speak>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Speechcon** of SSML.

**Hmm** is available in English India Speechcon. To include a speechcon in your skill's text-to-speech response, use the `<say-as interpret-as="interjection">` SSML tag

Ex:

```
<speak>
   <say-as interpret-as="interjection">hmm</say-as>
    <break time="0.5s"/> 
    You are right.
</speak>
```

List of supported English (India) [Speechcons](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/speechcon-reference-interjections-english-india.html#supported-speechcons)